# Replace plotoutput by leafletoutput on double click in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have an output from plotOutput and when there is a double click on the map, I want to see an output from leafletoutput. In the code below, when there is a double click on the map, the leaflet map shows below the google map. Before double click the the first image shows but after double clicking, I want to see the leaflet map only. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
   library(shiny)
   library(shinydashboard)
   library(leaflet)
   library(dismo)
   library(ggmap)
   library(dplyr)

 shinyApp(
 ui = dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title=""),

 dashboardSidebar(width = 200 ),


dashboardBody(   

  fluidRow(

    plotOutput("USA_GoogleMap",dblclick='plot_dblclick'),
    leafletOutput("leaflet_map")


  )
)),

 server=function(input, output, session) {

double_clicked <- reactiveValues(

center = NULL 
)

  # Handle double clicks on the plot

observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {

double_clicked$center <- c(input$plot_dblclick$x,input$plot_dblclick$y)

 })



output$USA_GoogleMap<-renderPlot({

statesMap = map_data("state")

xy=cbind(statesMap$long,statesMap$lat)
y=c(36.4,41.5,42.25,27.7,32.77)
x=c(-115.5,-100,-75,-81.5,-97.45)
state=c("Nevada","Nebraska","New York","Florida","Texas")
bases=cbind(x,y)
bases_mercator=data_frame(Mercator_X=Mercator(bases)[,1],Mercator_Y=Mercator(bases)[,2],State=state)


g = gmap(xy, type='satellite',zoom=4)   
plot(g, inter=TRUE)
points(Mercator(bases) , pch=20,cex=16, col=adjustcolor("white", alpha=0.2))
points(Mercator(bases) , pch=20,cex=16, col=adjustcolor("yellow", alpha=0.4))
text(bases_mercator$Mercator_X,bases_mercator$Mercator_Y,state)

})


 output$leaflet_map <- renderLeaflet({
if(!is.null(double_clicked$center)){

  leaflet()%>%setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 12)%>%addTiles()
 }
})
}
   )
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### First Image

[image]

#### Second image

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you would like the leaflet map to *replace* the plot? Not just have the leaflet appear, but the plot disappear with a blank white space where the plot was?

Comment: I would prefer not to have a white space where the plot was because that would not  be visually attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first preface this by saying - *there's a better way to do this than I'm showing.* I just haven't found one yet. I'm sure a much better programmer than I would know of it, but at least I can say this works. Even though it's hideous. The key to hiding the plot was using `conditionalPanel` (which I was previously unfamiliar with).

I have a text trigger for identifying whether or not the plot was double-clicked, and use that to trigger whether or not to show the panel. However, I couldn't get the text to initialize without calling it with textOutput... so I have a textOutput call with a font size of zero.  Again, there must be a **much** better way of triggering that than I'm doing it... but again, at least it works. Hopefully it will help.

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')
library('leaflet')
library('dismo')
library('ggmap')
library('dplyr')

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title=""),

    dashboardSidebar(width = 200 ),

    dashboardBody(   

      fluidRow(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = 'output.condition == 0',
          plotOutput("USA_GoogleMap",dblclick='plot_dblclick')
        ),
        leafletOutput("leaflet_map"),
        textOutput('condition'),
        tags$head(tags$style("#condition{font-size: 0px}"))

      )
    )),

  server=function(input, output, session) {

    double_clicked <- reactiveValues(

      center = NULL 
    )

    # Handle double clicks on the plot

    observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {

      double_clicked$center <- c(input$plot_dblclick$x,input$plot_dblclick$y)

    })

    output$USA_GoogleMap<-renderPlot({
      if(is.null(double_clicked$center)){
        statesMap = map_data("state")

        xy=cbind(statesMap$long,statesMap$lat)
        y=c(36.4,41.5,42.25,27.7,32.77)
        x=c(-115.5,-100,-75,-81.5,-97.45)
        state=c("Nevada","Nebraska","New York","Florida","Texas")
        bases=cbind(x,y)
        bases_mercator=data_frame(Mercator_X=Mercator(bases)[,1],Mercator_Y=Mercator(bases)[,2],State=state)

        g = gmap(xy, type='satellite',zoom=4)   
        plot(g, inter=TRUE)
        points(Mercator(bases) , pch=20,cex=16, col=adjustcolor("white", alpha=0.2))
        points(Mercator(bases) , pch=20,cex=16, col=adjustcolor("yellow", alpha=0.4))
        text(bases_mercator$Mercator_X,bases_mercator$Mercator_Y,state)

      }

    })


    output$leaflet_map <- renderLeaflet({
      if(!is.null(double_clicked$center)){

        leaflet()%>%setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 12)%>%addTiles()
      }
    })

    output$condition <- renderText({
      ifelse(!is.null(double_clicked$center), 1, 0)
    })

  }

)
```